# Generic function with switch

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to convert numbers(`Double`, `Float`, `CGFloat`, `Int32`) to `String`.

```
protocol DirectionStringConvertible {
    var direction: String { get }
}

extension Double: DirectionStringConvertible {
    var direction: String {
        switch self {
        case 0...11.24: return "N"
        case 11.25...33.74: return "NNE"
            ...
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}

extension CGFloat: DirectionStringConvertible { var direction: String { return Double(self).direction } }
extension Float: DirectionStringConvertible { var direction: String { return Double(self).direction } }
extension Int32: DirectionStringConvertible { var direction: String { return Double(self).direction } }
```

So I can use like below:

```
CGFloat(12).direction
Double(190).direction
```

However I want to know any better way with generic type. Something like

```
extension String {
    static func direction<T>(_ value: T) -> String {
        switch value {
        case 0...11.24: return "N"
        case 11.25...33.74: return "NNE"
          ...
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the answer was deleted, but I liked the idea of using FloatingPoint protocol. I’ll try that.

Comment: I deleted it because you said you wanted it to work on `Int32`, too, which is not a floating point type. But I've undeleted that answer in case you wanted to refer to it.

Comment: Got it. Is there any protocol which is conformed by most number types in swift?

Comment: There are (e.g. `Numeric`), but then you can't use my calculation of `value`...

Comment: By the way, as a general observation, I'd warn you against using closed ranges like you have in your snippet. What if the value was 11.245? I think you want half-open ranges, using the same value for the open upper end of one range and the closed lower end of the next range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I went to generic pattern, I'd wonder if you couldn't just use existing `FloatingPoint` protocol, to which all floating point types already conform:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var direction: String {
        let value = ((self - 32 / 360) * 16 / 360).rounded()
        switch value {
        case 0: return "N"
        case 1: return "NNE"
        case 2: return "NE"
        case 3: return "ENE"
        case 4: return "E"
        case 5: return "ESE"
        case 6: return "SE"
        case 7: return "SSE"
        case 8: return "S"
        case 9: return "SSW"
        case 10: return "SW"
        case 11: return "WSW"
        case 12: return "W"
        case 13: return "WNW"
        case 14: return "NW"
        case 15: return "NNW"
        case 16: return "N"
        default: return "???"
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously only works on floating point types, but perhaps this is sufficient for your purposes. If you want, as rmaddy pointed out, you can write a `BinaryInteger` extension, that casts integer types to floating point types, and it can then use the above:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var direction: String { 
        return Double(Int(self)).direction
    }
}
```

---

Or you can do a `Numeric` extension, where they are `Comparable`, multiplying by some factor so that the threshold values are integers:

```
extension Numeric where Self: Comparable {
    var direction: String {
        switch self * 4 {
        case 0    ..< 45:   return "N"
        case 45   ..< 135:  return "NNE"
        case 135  ..< 225:  return "NE"
        case 225  ..< 315:  return "ENE"
        case 315  ..< 405:  return "E"
        case 405  ..< 495:  return "ESE"
        case 495  ..< 585:  return "SE"
        case 585  ..< 675:  return "SSE"
        case 675  ..< 765:  return "S"
        case 765  ..< 855:  return "SSW"
        case 855  ..< 945:  return "SW"
        case 945  ..< 1035: return "WSW"
        case 1035 ..< 1125: return "W"
        case 1125 ..< 1215: return "WNW"
        case 1215 ..< 1305: return "NW"
        case 1305 ..< 1395: return "NNW"
        case 1395 ... 1440: return "N"
        default: return "???"
        }
    }
}
```

Or Alain's approach of multiplying by 100 makes the ranges a little less cryptic.

Comment: Maybe I can use Numeric protocol. I’ll try this as well

Comment: You can add `extension BinaryInteger { var direction: String { return Double(Int(self)).direction } }` to support Integer types.

Comment: @rmaddy - That's a nice. +1. It does feel like there should be a more elegant solution to this, though.

Comment: That `switch` could be replaced with indexing into an array. Much more concise

Comment: @Alexander - Perhaps you can post an answer showing us what that would look like, because it's not nearly as obvious as it might appear.

Comment: @Rob It's not a full answer, just an amendment to the first part of yours. You could define an array containing `["N", "NNE", ... "NNW", "N"]`, then index into it: `return directionLabels.indices.contains(value) ? directionLabels[value] : "???"`

Comment: But you cannot use `value` as a subscript. It is a protocol type.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the Numeric Protocol.

For example:

```
func direction<T:Numeric>(_ a:T)-> String where T:Comparable
{
   let dirNames = ["NNE","NE","ENE","E","ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW","NW","NNW","N"]
                  .reduce([(1125 as T,"N")]){ $0 + [($0.last!.0+2250,$1)]}
   return a < 0 ? direction(a + 360) : dirNames.first{ a * 100 < $0.0}?.1 ?? direction(a - 360)                         
}
```

By using integer comparison values (multiplied by 100 for 2 digit precision), the function will work for integer parameters without having to define two separate sets of values.

Using an extension and a switch statement, it could look like this:

```
extension Numeric where Self:Comparable
{
    var direction:String 
    {
       switch self * 100
       {
         case 0..<1125         : return "N"
         case 1125..<3375      : return "NNE"
         case 3375..<5625      : return "NE"
         // ...
         case 33750..<36000    : return "N"

         case _ where self < 0 : return (self + 360).direction
         default               : return (self - 360).direction
       }                                                         
    }
}
```